# Key Hook не определяет 4 кнопки сразу

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

Хочу выводить нажатые клавиши пользователем, в том числе сочетания. Пробовал разные Key Lisener/Hook (они работают по одному и тому же принципу), но везде одна и та же проблема - у меня получается нажать 4 клавиши одновременно: `A + S + D + F`, но вот никак не получается нажать `G + H + V` или все 4 стрелочки.

Хотелось бы поддерживать 5 одновременных нажатий.

Использую этот гист: https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698

Код формы:

```
public partial class KeyDisplayerForm : Window
{
    private KeyboardListener KListener;
    private List<string> keys;

    public KeyDisplayerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KListener = new KeyboardListener();
        KListener.KeyDown += new RawKeyEventHandler(KListener_KeyDown);
        KListener.KeyUp += new RawKeyEventHandler(KListener_KeyUp);

        keys = new List<string>();
    }

    private void KListener_KeyUp(object sender, RawKeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keys.RemoveAll(x => x == e.Key.ToString());
        Show();
    }

    private void KListener_KeyDown(object sender, RawKeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!keys.Exists(x => x == e.Key.ToString()))
        {
            keys.Add(e.Key.ToString());
            Show();
        }
    }

    private void Show()
    {
        label.Content = "";
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            label.Content += $"{key} + "; 
        }
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        KListener.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Разметка формы:

```
<Window x:Class="YAKD.KeyDisplayerForm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YAKD"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="KeyDisplayerForm"
        Height="200" Width="500"
        Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Но ведь это не баг. Нажатие даже трех буквенных клавиш одновременно воспринимается как некорректный ввод ("кошка на клавиатуре"). Без прямого опроса состояния клавиатуры вряд ли предусмотрена обработка такого.

Comment: Что интересно — это зависит от ПК/ОС, одни и те же комбинации на одном ПК могут не отлавливаться на другом. Сталкивался с этим.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я не говорил про баг, я подразумеваю, что это некая особенность ОС, мне интересно как с этом бороться и возможно ли?

Comment: У меня на Linux происходит нечто странное при нажатии более 4х клавиш, так что я думаю это не баг или еще что, а особенность девайса, возможно он не поддерживает множественные нажатия.

Comment: Попробуйте в цикле через GetAsyncKeyState получать состояние всех клавиш и отслеживать изменения. Если не получится, скорее всего это особенность железа или драйвера.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, попробовал, тот же результат. Видимо такова работа системы.

Comment: Это "особенность" клавиатуры. Производители экономят, за счет переиспользования проводящих дорожек так-сказать. Обычно можно отловить одновременное нажатие стандартных "геймерских" клавиш, и то не на всех моделях. На старых механических клавиатурах удавалось ловить до 5 одновременно нажатых клавиш, на новых и 2 не всегда ловятся, зависит от распайки. А "кошка на клавиатуре" учитывает также минимальную и максимальную длительности нажатия, если используется.

Comment: @rdorn хороший ответ, продублируйте как ответ - я отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это аппаратная проблема. Зависит исключительно от разводки проводящих дорожек для клавиш и, иногда, от контроллера.

Обычно можно отловить одновременное нажатие стандартных "геймерских" клавиш, и то не на всех моделях. На бюджетных пленочных - 2-3 клавиши потолок, и то не любые, как повезет. На более дорогих моделях и старых механических может быть больше, иногда существенно.