# Поймать клик мышью и клик на клавиатуре на всём экране C#

Tags: c#

Необходимо поймать событие клика мыши по всему экрану и клика по клавиатуре. Посоветуйте библиотеки для разработки на C#. Или код на С++.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте key/mouse хуки через `WinAPI`. Вот, например, [готовый гист](https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698) для работы с клавиатурой.

Для мышки посмотрите хуки [`WH_MOUSE_LL`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_mouse_llhook) и [`WH_MOUSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_mouse_llhook).

Возможно, вам будет интересен [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846622/key-hook-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-4-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83) по это теме.

Comment: @Llirik21 если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.